# Eloquent ORM order by deep relation

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, sql-order-by

Models:

1. Category (id, name)
2. Item (id, name, category_id, ...)
3. OrderList (id, user_id, ...)
4. OrderListItem(id, item_id, order_list_id, user_sort_order, ...)

I want OrderListItems of each OrderList to be sorted:

- By user_sort_order
- Or by Category name

What I do:

```
$grouped = $request->input('grouped', false) === "true";
            $user = User::findOrFail($id);
            $order_lists = OrderList::where('kitchen_id', $user->id)
                ->with(['order_list_items' => function ($q) use ($grouped) {
                    $q->when($grouped, function ($q) {
                        return $q->with(['item' => function ($q) {
                            return $q->with(['category' => function ($q) {
                                return $q->orderBy('name', 'asc');
                            }]);
                        }]);
                    }, function ($q) {
                        return $q->orderBy('kitchen_sort_order', 'asc');
                    })->with('supplier')
                        ->with(['item' => function ($q) {
                            return $q->with('category');
                        }]);
                }])->get();
```

Ordering by category name isn't working. I had been searching for hours but found no answer. Is it possible to do something like this in Eloquent ORM? Btw, Django is able to do it in a really nice way.

Comment: You need to use joins to sort by related fields. It isn't possible using only Eloquent, afaik.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `HasManyThrough` relationship as a `BelongsToThrough` and combine it with a modified `withCount().`Not the most elegant solution, but it works:

```
class OrderListItem extends Model {
    public function category() {
        return $this->hasManyThrough(Category::class, Item::class,
            'id', 'id', 'item_id', 'category_id');
    }
}

$order_lists = OrderList::where('kitchen_id', $user->id)
    ->with(['order_list_items' => function ($q) use ($grouped) {
        $q->when($grouped, function ($q) {
            return $q->withCount(['category as category_name' => function ($q) {
                $q->select('categories.name');
            }])->orderBy('category_name');
        }, function ($q) {
            return $q->orderBy('kitchen_sort_order', 'asc');
        })->with('supplier')
            ->with(['item' => function ($q) {
                return $q->with('category');
            }]);
    }])->get();
```

Comment: Can you please give feedback on the answer?